# Install clang6, libc++6 and libc++6abi on Debian stretch

Tags: debian, clang, libc++

I have just spent the whole day desperately trying to install clang6 with libc++6 and libc++6abi on a freshly installed, completely empty Debian stretch (it’s actually a clean Docker image).

The fact that I failed is extremely frustrating. Is there any place where I can find out exactly what to do, starting from scratch and without assuming any prior knowledge in the matter?